# Confusion regarding active band pass filter

Tags: filter, passive-filter, terminology

I have seen some Google results where a band pass filter is made by cascading low pass and high pass stages. I am confused what will happen if we interchange the stages (first stage is high pass and second stage is low pass.) Will it convert the band pass filter into a band stop filter?

Comment: draw it on paper ... it will become a non-question

Answer (score 5):

The first question with respect to a multi-stage bandpass filter is whether or not it should be implemented as a single ***narrow*** filter (the entire system is designed together as a single high-\$Q\$ piece) or implemented as a ***wideband*** filter with separated LP sections and HP sections.

I mentioned \$Q\$, but the concept can get kind of muddied up if you are thinking in terms of higher-order filter functions. So I prefer to look at the [fractional bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(signal_processing)#Fractional_bandwidth), instead, since this is a clearer concept, regardless of the filter order.

- fractional bandwidth: \$B_{_\text{F}}=\frac{f_{_\text{H}}\:-\: f_{_\text{L}}}{f_{_\text{C}}}\$
- where: \$f_{_\text{C}}=\sqrt{f_{_\text{L}}\cdot f_{_\text{H}}}\$ (the geometric center frequency)

(When limited to 2nd order, the above directly relates to \$Q\$ and \$\zeta\$.)

For \$B_{_\text{F}}\$ below 1, or better still below .8, then the multi-stage filter should ***not*** be designed using separate cascaded HP and LP sections and instead should be designed as a whole, interacting piece. Otherwise, using separate cascaded HP and LP sections is probably better.

Here is where some bit of art comes to play. There isn't a single dividing line that I've seen. Usually, a specific situation lies clearly to one side or another, so you don't have to pause and think more. Different authors appear to draw different lines, though (likely because the situation starts to look more like a balancing of many different factors and not everyone shares the exact same view of them.)

There's a bit of conflating ideas in my above writing. For example, the decision might be between implementing a bandpass filter as a single opamp (2nd order) to save some money/space or to use a cascaded approach (both 2nd order, so effectively 4th order) that will have better rejection in the stop bands. But this is also comparing 2nd order vs 4th order. So there isn't a single thread of thought here and I can't afford to include every consideration here. But in general, as \$f_{_\text{L}}\$ and \$f_{_\text{H}}\$ approach each other, the responses of the stages in a multi-stage filter increasingly interact.

In cases where the fractional bandwidth suggests cascaded LP and HP stages, and there are only two such, then the HP stage usually comes first so that the HF noise it generates will be low-passed out by the following LP stage.

Of course, there are also band-stops. But if you are instead only worried that if an original bandpass filter using a separate HP and LP stage (meaning that the fractional bandwidth is large enough to justify that approach) have their stages swapped, that it might become a bandstop. This is ***not*** the case. It will still be a bandpass. But it may be noisier or it may load the input differently or it may not drive the following sections in the same way. Loading and noise will likely change.

Answer (score 3):

No, it will still be a band pass filter. It does not matter in which order you filter.

Answer (score 2):

> *I have seen some google results where band pass filter is made by
> \$\color{red}{\text{cascading low pass}}\$\$\color{red}{\text{& high pass stages}}\$. I am confused what will happen
> if we interchange the stages (first stage is high pass and second stage
> is low pass). Will it convert our band pass filter to band stop filter
> ?*

Theoretically there is no difference but, there can be "real circuit" considerations: -

- If you have a multi stage filter (such as two 2nd order low-pass filters) you *should* put the stage with the lowest Q-factor first. This ensures that the intermediary output point (that feeds the final stage) doesn't clip due to having higher Q compared to the lower Q final stage.
- This of course also applies to your circuit and, it's likely that you should put the stage with the lowest Q first in line. All, I'm saying is: think about the p-p voltage that might arise at the node between the two stages - ensure this can't clip (limited supply voltages) or your final output may seem a little strange as if some kind of AGC (or compression) were being used.

I think for your circuit, I'd be putting the high-pass first for another reason too; if the high-pass stage does have a little peaking at its low-frequency cut-off point, it's quite likely that this won't clash with the high-frequency cut-off point produced by the 2nd stage low-pass filter. But, if the HP has quite a "peaky" response AND the LP is quite tame, then I'd put the low-pass filter first.

I first found this years ago when I designed a 12th order low-pass filter made of op-amps and got really crappy quality. So, it's not something I'm inventing; been there, bought the T-shirt.

$$\color{red}{\text{If in doubt, simulators are going to be really helpful before you commit to copper}}$$

Answer (score 1):

As you know, bandpass filter allows an interval of frequency. If you first place lowpass filter, your highest frequency will be determined. Then second filter(highpass) will set lowest frequency can pass.

If you change location of them, it will be vice versa. Highpass filter will determine the lowest frequency that can pass. And the second one(lowpass) will determine the highest frequency.

So, changing cascade order will not change features of bandpass filter theoretically. It will not change into bandstop filter.